# JSON API to PHP Array using file_get_contents

Tags: php, json

Friends, help with the code. I have json data, i want to display value "price". I can't figure out how to do this.

```
{
   "success":true,
   "data":{
      "DXB":{
         "0":{
            "price":33915,
            "airline":"DP",
            "flight_number":991,
            "departure_at":"2023-03-30T08:00:00+03:00",
            "return_at":"2023-04-20T15:20:00+04:00",
            "expires_at":"2023-03-28T04:45:51Z"
         },
         "1":{
            "price":31997,
            "airline":"J2",
            "flight_number":182,
            "departure_at":"2024-01-03T12:20:00+03:00",
            "return_at":"2024-01-12T14:10:00+04:00",
            "expires_at":"2023-03-28T04:45:51Z"
         },
         "2":{
            "price":34593,
            "airline":"DP",
            "flight_number":423,
            "departure_at":"2023-04-02T08:00:00+03:00",
            "return_at":"2023-04-22T17:00:00+04:00",
            "expires_at":"2023-03-28T04:45:51Z"
         }
      }
   },
   "currency":"rub"
}
```

```
<?php

$get_data = file_get_contents('ai url');


$get_data = json_decode($get_data);


?>


<?php foreach($get_data as $g): ?>


<h5><?php echo $g->price;?></h5>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

I tried the code that attached the gist, it returns null.

Tell me how to display data in sublevel json

Comment: `foreach ($get_data->data->DXB as $g)`

Comment: Phil, thank you very much for your help, everything worked out. Data received :)